# Build tile server manually with PostgreSQL db on a different server

Tags: openstreetmap, tile-server, amazon-web-services, mod-tile

I have set up my map tile server and have used the following components:

1. Mod_tile
2. osm2pgsql
3. postgres
4. Mapnik
5. open street map carto

In my configuration, postgres is on a different server. when I access the /osm_tiles/0/0/0.png, I get a blank square. I think the data is not being fetched from postgres database. I have mentioned the configuration in the osm2pgsql/project.yaml file.

1. How do I tell my server that the PostgreSQL db is on another server? Do I need to mention the db details in some other place as well?
2. Which of tool fetches the tiles from the PostgreSQL db to be displayed?

P.s I've used this [link](https://github.com/s6o/aws-osm-rds) as the setup guide.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/68173/build-tile-server-manually-with-postgres-db-on-a-different-server

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**
In the project-1.mml file (at [this step](https://github.com/s6o/aws-osm-rds#create-mapnik-configuration)) check the database value and rerun carto command:

```
carto project-1.mml > OSMDefault.xml
```

Values should like:

```
  osm2pgsql: &osm2pgsql
    type: "postgis"
    dbname: "gis"
    host: "<your-server-zone>.rds.amazonaws.com"
    user: "postgres"
    password: "<your-postgres-password>"
    ...
```

If you still have diffculties check the connection between your Mapnik EC2 instance and your database.

```
psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <username> -W <password> <database>
```

If you can't connect check your security groups the database server security group must allow inbound traffic from the mapnik server. A recommended practice is to reference the security group of the mapnik server from the security group definition of the database server (see details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules)).

**Question 2**

This is Mapnik that fetch the data from PostgreSQL and generate the tiles.
**The tiles are not in the database**, this is Mapnik that generate them using geospatial data from the database and a stylesheet (to select the rendering colors and size of all elements)

Comment: can we use port in this config? something like this:--
osm2pgsql: &osm2pgsql
  type: "postgis"
  dbname: "gis"
  port: 5433